# Trying to get my bot on discord to work… Running node.js as my final step and I get errors

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

```
C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\MyBot>node bot.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'auth.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\MyBot\bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\MyBot\bot.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\Intel\\Desktop\\MyBot\\bot.js' ]
}
```

Please help, I've been stuck, and I'm trying to move on with this tutorial so I can start actually building the bot!

Comment: I'm not certain anyone can help you without having seen this project before.  The error message is pretty explicit, focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a local file.

Local modules/files have to be loaded like `require("./auth.json");`, otherwise node will look In the node_modules folder.

For future questions: It may be nice if you could provide a few more details next time

Comment: Yeah, will do. I apologize for the lack of info provided, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Make sure to still check this answer as working solution, so others can find it easier